# XY Coordinate conversion for google maps

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps

I have coordinates in XY format for System 22/17.

I wish to convert them to plot on google maps. Any help?

Comment: Many GIS can do this.  Are you looking for a one time conversion or multiple conversions?  Do you already have something in mind?  Have you tried any programs in the past?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with QGIS:

Load the data as delimited text, assigning `EPSG:29377  Schwarzeck / Lo22/17` as CRS when prompted.

Save the data to a new file, format `CSV`, `EPSG:4326 WGS84` as CRS, and check `Geometry as XY`.

The same can be done with GDAL ogr2ogr on the command line, or python code if you are used to that.